# Next dropdown menu cant have value already used in another dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button that adds dropdown menu's to the page in javascript. The dropdown menu's all get the same values but I want to be able to make sure the other dropdown menu's cant have the same value as an option when it's already selected by another dropdown menu.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on('click', function(){
            $("<tr><td><select class='selectClass' name='something[]' ><?php echo $s; ?></select></td>
             </tr>").appendTo("table");

         i++;
    });
});
```

The $s are the options:

```
foreach ($values as $object) {
    $s .= '<option value=\''.$object->id.'\'>
    '.$object->name.'</option>';
}
```

I know I should get the values of the options that's selected in javascript. After that I should compare that option to all the `$object->id` 's in the  `foreach`. If it matches, I should not add that option to the variable `$s` but I have no idea how to do this. The thing is, there can be like 5 dropdown menu's and none of them should be having the possibility to get the same option as the one that's selected in the other 4. The values that aren't selected should just be available in the dropdown menu.

How do I actually do this? I was thinking about something with [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) but I really have no idea if this is the way or not and how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this by using jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.selectClass', function (e) {
        removeOthr();           
    });

    function removeOthr()
    {

        //enable all options///
        $('.selectClass option').each(function () {
            // $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            $(this).show();
        });

        $('.selectClass option:selected').each(function () {
           var select = $(this).parent(),
           optValue = $(this).val();
           // alert(optValue);

           if($(this).val()!=''){
               $('.selectClass').not(select).children().filter(function(e){
                   if($(this).val()==optValue)
                       return e
               // }).prop('disabled', true);
               }).hide();
           }
        });
    }
});
```

**Just assign selectClass to every dropdown.**

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sunilpachlangia/8mon4d0q/)

By this code (Suppose) you have dropdown that contains A,B,C,D,E,F in option. Then once user select A from any dropdown then "A" will be removed all other dropdown. Same will apply for all options. And again unselecting that option that will be available further.

Comment: I assigned selectClass to every dropdown but it's not doing anything.

Comment: I updated the class='selectClass' and I copied and pasted your answer above the javascript.

Comment: You can see working jsfiddel here.  https://jsfiddle.net/sunilpachlangia/8mon4d0q/

Comment: I dont get it. It looks great on the JSFiddle but it's just not working for me. I have this code in my question right now and your Jquery. That's it.

Comment: may be there is a problem with your jQuery version problem.That's why onchange event is not working in this way. Try other way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72916/discussion-between-sunil-pachlangia-and-loko).